# How do I float this div straightly?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have been examining [THIS](http://www.arkanbuilds.com/#header-main) this for a while and decided to test on it. If you scroll lower, you'll find a section that mentions 'High quality'.... I have made a similar div, and want to do something similar, but each time it turns out like [THIS](http://gyazo.com/aa78651e9e17336ea6229f4f9ac33874) (ignore the golden colour) - What might the code be to fix this small issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *align*, I assume you mean *float*. If you look at their markup, you'll see that they're using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and the alignment is handled using its in-built [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), for example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 column"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 column"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose, thanks for the answer; but now how do I make it how it is on their site?

Comment: @arrey What do you mean *make it how it is on their site*? I already explained, they use Bootstrap...

Comment: Right, do you suggest I must use bootstrap too? Thing is, I don't really know what it is... Any way I can make them in a straight fashion like it is on that Site without boostrap? Any code you recommend?

Comment: Yes, `float: left; width: 33%` in CSS will achieve what you're looking for. But that's another question entirely. You should accept this answer if it's helped, since it directly answers your original question.

Comment: You need to ask another question, providing your current code and with what you'd like to achieve. That is outside the scope of this question (and the answer I posted above).

Comment: Sorry, but this happened? xD
http://gyazo.com/5122f88d63cf3c1d1afdd0cc8b07f445
background went messed up?

Comment: As I said, this is another question entirely. Your original question here was how they achieved it. I answered that. It's Bootstrap. If you have more questions, please ask them as separate questions here on StackOverflow.

Comment: So... *So, how did they align it straight? I have been trying to look for it for hours xD*?

Comment: Alrighty, thanks, however may I not receive an answer? xD

Comment: @arrey you are either a troll or incredible ignorant.

Comment: May I ask why this is....? What have I done wrong...?

Comment: @BenM
Hey mate... Um... A question.. Why does my post have so many downvotes, and why did Nico call me ignorant, as in, apologies you probably don't know... It's just what have I done wrong.. I had a question and came to ask it...?

Comment: The problem is that you asked a question, got an answer, and then asked more questions on the same thread. If you have additional questions, they need to be asked as separate questions on Stack Overflow - it's not a Forum. Your question has many downvotes because you could have easily inspected the CSS and HTML of the web page and found out why the alignment is as it is.

Comment: @arrey sorry when i've been too harsh. I watched the conversation of you and BenM, and saw that you replied instantly whithout even seem to think about what was said. I apologize when i did you wrong.

Comment: Sorry guys I never knew..... But @BenM the reason why I replied on here cause I'm apparently temp-banned on asking more questions because I got too many downvotes, *Sigh :(